# C#: Is there a way to make a field of one instance readonly when referenced by other instances of any class?

Tags: c#

would there be a way to make it so that `tastesGood` can only be redefined within `Apple` but can still be referenced by `Jim`?

```cs
public class Apple {
    public bool tastesGood = true;

    void ChangeYourMind() {
        tastesGood = false;
    }
}

public class Jim {
    void EatApple() {
        if (tastesGood) {
            Speak("mmmmm!");
        } else {
            Speak("Yuck!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you coming to C# from a JavaScript background?

Comment: Does `Jim` inherit from, or encapsulate, `Apple`? And what do you mean by "redefined"? Do you mean re-assigned?

Comment: This is where an [mcve] would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't expose fields from classes. Instead expose the value as a property with **a public getter, but a private setter**. C# uses a different syntax for properties vs. fields.

```
public class Apple {

    public bool TastesGood { get; private set; } = true;

    public void ChangeYourMind()
    {
        this.TastesGood = false;
    }
}
```

Other tips:

- In .NET the standard naming convention is to always use `PascalCase` (as opposed to `camelCase`) for all public members of classes/structs/interfaces.
- The example you posted is of an object-oriented class with *mutable state* - which is fine as I assume you're getting familiar with programming or C#, but I'll advise you that the programming field over the past decade or so is trending towards *immutable* state and adopting more functional-programming approaches, so keep your eyes open for any articles about FP as you'll learn better when you're still young and malleable.

Comment: @jonskeet can you edit my answer again (I missed your edit, sorry!) so this answer can proudly display the "Edited by Jon Skeet" that I'll treasure for life? and maybe brag about at the pub...

Comment: Edited just to remove the bit saying that I'd edited it, which isn't really relevant for other users. Hopefully that works for everyone...